# Multiple users on one profile?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

Does anyone have any solutions for multiple users using one profile? Looking for something like profile2 but with the option open for more than one person to use a single profile. Say for instance a company name or organization.

Comment: I suppose I could do this with taxonomy, views, and rules... Rules to give the option of manager to switch roles once sign on and comparison boolean... is there another way...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Views sounds like a way to go. You could have separate *employee* and *company* profiles (where *employee* profile references *company*), and then add a view to each company profile listing all its employees.